# Interrupt super.onCreate() in super class

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have a base Activity in which I want to check authentication for all Activities that require to be logged in, both `onCreate` and `onResume`:

For example HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AccountRequiredActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

}

public class AccountRequiredActivity extends LifecycleActivity {
    private final int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Inject
    ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

    private AccountViewModel accountViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        accountViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(AccountViewModel.class);
        checkAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkAuthentication();
    }

    private void checkAuthentication() {
        // Check if authenticated synchronously
        if(!accountViewModel.isAuthenticated()) {
            getLogin();
        };
    }

    private void getLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == INTENT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // The login is ok, continue
            } else {
                getLogin();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`LoginActivity` is a separate activity that manages the login flow (connection to FB server and my own).

There are 2 problems with this code.
The first problem is that when `isAuthenticated` is false, I don't want the method to return to the calling child Activity (in this case, `HomeActivity`) because setContentView of Home should not be set.
The second problem is that `onActivityResult`is called asynchronously (as is the login flow in `LoginActivity` as a matter of fact.

How do I fix this code so that I'm able to make the auth check in the base class, while only continuing to call `setContentView` when the authentication succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the base `Activity` do something like this:

```
@Override
protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Do your authentication stuff here
    if (auth is successfull) {
        // Call derived Activity's "doOnCreate()" to set content view, etc.
        doOnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        // Here you can do whatever you need to do in case the auth fails
    }
}
```

Declaring the method `final` prevents derived activities from overriding it.

Also create an abstract method `doOnCreate()` in the base `Activity` that each derived `Activity` needs to override.

Each derived `Activity` should NOT override `onCreate()`, but implement `doOnCreate()` and implement all of its initialization there.

Comment: Sorry it took some time to verify it, I was very busy this week. But it works!